# R sequence from matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sequence

I have matrix like

```
> brdrs <- matrix(c(-1,-0.2,0.2,3),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
> brdrs
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] -1.0 -0.2
[2,]  0.2  3.0
```

I want to make sequence, based on this matrix. First column is the start of interval, second- the end. Each row is interval of one sequence.

For example it would be: from -1.0 to -0.2 AND from 0.2 to 3.0 by 0.1.

Is it possible without loops?

Thanks

Comment: guess, this is a part of solution, but this works only for one sequence with one gap in it

`setdiff(seq(-1.0,3.0), seq(-0.2,0.2))`

Comment: @AnandaMahto by 0.05 for example

Comment: @AnandaMahto I edited question, for the future. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this :

```
unlist(sapply(1:nrow(brdrs),function(x){seq(brdrs[x,1],brdrs[x,2],0.1)}))

[1] -1.0 -0.9 -0.8 -0.7 -0.6 -0.5 -0.4 -0.3 -0.2  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
[18]  1.0  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0  2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6
[35]  2.7  2.8  2.9  3.0
```

Like Ananda Mahto said in the comment, you should specify the increment of the sequence. Here, I used 0.1

Comment: @IgorMatsko: You're welcome. Note that if you have a larger number of rows and if they are not ordered (eg `matrix(c(-1,-0.2,0.2,3,-2,-1.5),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)`) , you might want to use `sort` at the start of the command so that the sequence will be ordered.